# Trying to pass values as navigation params but cant get the parameter in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement i18n on my app, i've set a file named `SettingsScreen.js`, this file has a lot buttons to change languages (see the example below), and another file called `HomeScreen.js`, this file was supposed to get the param passed through `SettingsScreen.js` and change the language of the app, but i got this error:

[image]

So i'm gonna post the rest of the code below:

***HomeScreen.js:***

```
export default function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  let { lang } = route.params;

  i18n.locale = lang;

  <Rest of the content/>
}
```

***SettingsScreen.js:***

```
export default function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  let setPortuguese = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Dashboard", { 
      screen: "HomeScreen", 
      params: { lang: "pt" } 
    })

    <Rest of the content />
  }
}
```

***app.js:***

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please paste the error traceback as _text_ in a code block, not as a picture of text. Pictures of text can't be copied or searched.

Comment: ofcourse, sorry about this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is calling `navigation.navigate` passing wrongs params.

Try this code:

***SettingsScreen.js:***

```js
export default function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  let setPortuguese = () => {
    navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", {
      lang: "pt"
    })

    <Rest of the content />
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and still doesnt working, got the same error :x

Comment: Which 'react-navigation' version are you using?

Comment: im using 5.3.2 on /stack and 5.7.2 on /drawer

Comment: See my edit. Try the new HomeScreen.js approach. I used 'navigation.getParam' to get your lang param.

Comment: i tried and got this error: TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function. maybe missing a importation?

Comment: So, i just undo my last edit. Can you do => console.log(route) inside HomeScreen.js, and show me the log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214860/discussion-between-maycon-mesquita-and-pedro-guilherme).

Comment: I appreciate your attencion mate, you really helped me alot!